# Expect sends 0x0d (\r, carriage return) program receives 0x0a (\n, new line)

Tags: c, passwords, expect

I am trying to automate [no-ip client](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client/) configuration with Expect. The script (`make install`) runs the compiled `noip2.c` which requires entering an email and password to the service.

It seems that `\r` are somehow treated by this program as a part of the password. I use the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn sudo make install

expect "email string for no-ip.com" { send "my@email.com\r" }
expect "password for user" { send "mypassword\r" }
```

It does however cause receiving program to wait indefinitely (`\r` seemingly ignored). With `exp_internal 1` option I got the following confirmation of characters sent:

```
send: sending "mypassword\r" to { exp6 }
```

The `noip2` receives characters one by one and masks each one with an asterisk. The code for handling the password input looks like this:

```
do {
  if (read(0, &ch, 1) != 1)
    continue;
  if (ch == 0x0d)
    break;
  if ((ch == 0x08) || (ch == 0x7f)) {
    putchar(8);
    putchar(' ');
    putchar(8);
    x--;
  } else {
    *x++ = ch;
    putchar('*');
  }
  fflush(stdout);
} while (1);
```

I added `printf("%.2x", ch);` next to `putchar('*');` and **got `0x0a` for the `\r` character** sent from Expect (full result: `*0x6d*0x79*0x70*0x61*0x73*0x73*0x77*0x6f*0x72*0x64*0x0a`).

---

Next I changed the Expect script line to:

```
expect "password for user" { send "mypassword\x0d" }
```

and got the same:

```
*0x6d*0x79*0x70*0x61*0x73*0x73*0x77*0x6f*0x72*0x64*0x0a
```

When I changed to:

```
expect "password for user" { send "mypassword\x0b" }
```

I got:

```
*0x6d*0x79*0x70*0x61*0x73*0x73*0x77*0x6f*0x72*0x64*0x0b
```

Something is clearly interfering and changing `0x0d` to `0x0a` between Expect and the relevant part of the `noip2` program. What might be the reason?

Comment: Can you add `exp_internal 1` to your code and check what value actually being sent ? Share the result

Comment: @Dinesh It showed `send: sending "mypassword\r" to { exp6 }`. I updated my question based on further research of the code. Though Expect claims to be sending `0x0d`, receiving code gets `0x0a`.